# Using MzCom in another application

Tags: racket

I play arround with mzcom. And have some questions.
What is the status of this modul?
Is it usable for implementing in another application(c++) for serious use?
What do I have to respect when I must load a file with some scheme code in it?
For example (printf , display, newline) do not give me some values(#).

thanx in advance Ismail

Comment: It is now maintained by Matthew, and he's been doing some work on that recently.  So it's best to ask about using it on the [mailing list](http://racket-lang.org/community.html).

Answer (score 0):

In case someone stumbles onto this question in the future, here is a mailing list thread with more information:

http://www.mail-archive.com/users@racket-lang.org/msg13032.html